# TableView Chat Extend Message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

1.) How can I extend the message in my chat so it configures the tableView block to the size of the message without adding the "....." at the end.

2.) When I hit send the message uploads to Database but not to the tableView until i re-load the controller? What is the best way to go about fixing this?

3.) Load the table view so it shows the last message posted at the bottom?

Image of my tableView:

[image: 1]

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

struct postStruct {
    let username : String!
    let message : String!
    let photoURL : String!
}

class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!

    var generalRoomDataArr = [postStruct]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("general_room").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            let message = snapDict?["Message"] as? String ?? ""
            let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

            self.generalRoomDataArr.insert(postStruct(username: username, message: message, photoURL: firebaseUserPhotoURL), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToRoom", sender: nil)
    }


    //Message Send button is pressed data uploaded to firebase
    @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let message : String = self.messageTextField.text!
        UploadGeneralChatRoom(message: message) //update general_room
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
        //UploadUserData() //Update Rank in database
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username

        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message


        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //User Profile image in tableview
        if generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL != nil
        {
            //let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

            if let url = NSURL(string: generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL) {

                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {

                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                }
            }
        }







        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer for Q.1:

You can set the **number of lines** of your message *label* to **0**; It will extend your label vertically, if you have a lot of texts.

you may also need to set the *tableView's* row height to *automaticDimension* as follow:-

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

> Answer for Q.2:

Try reloading your `tableView` after you add it to `UploadUserData()`.

> Answer for Q.3:

If you want to just reverse the sorting behaviour than instead of sort you need to use reverse property

```
yourdataArray.reverse()
```

Comment: when i set the numberOfLine = 0 it still doesnt move to the next line

Comment: It may occur due to assigning fixed height constraint.

Comment: how should i go about it

Comment: You must not assign a label's height constraint; or any view which is related to height of the label